# Educate language server (ts) about extensions made by loaders

Tags: typescript, types, webpack-loader, typescript-language-server

If you make a loader, the editor (vscode) screams with red lines for these

Lets say we want to interpolate process output as code like this

index.js

```js
//this is a line handled by the loader
> npx ts-node --skip-project someSnippet arg1 arg2
```

Of course language server screams

but:

- when you import `json` language server knows very precise type of your json (not just declare record)
- even when you use embedded languages like when using `styled components` you get detailed type of the variable/component.

Where does this "type injection" happen and how?

- in case of loaders
- in case of embedded languages

i tried searching the web but cant find even the general concepts of how to do this
i tried digging trough source of the styled components but didnt really figure it out